# How to keep SSH connection alive?

Tags: ssh

How can I keep an SSH connection alive without actively using it. When I use it, it works fine, but when I don't use it for a few minutes, it disconnects. As I get an email each time I connect, how can I keep the SSH session alive?

Note: In my `.ssh/config` file, at the top I have

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 3
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What ssh client ? 3 is too short, use an interval of 60. You can also put that in /etc/ssh/ssh_config if you have root access.

Comment: `*` should be all of them, shouldn't it?

Comment: I do not think that works with PuTTY

Comment: Check the following url for PuTTy instructions https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/accessing-your-account/keeping-ssh-connections-alive

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to specify amount of the tries and interval of sending a packet to the server. You can put the following lines in your `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host examplehost
    Hostname examplehost.com
    ServerAliveInterval 180
    ServerAliveCountMax 2
```

This will send a packet to the server every 180 seconds (3 minutes) and it will try two times before it closes the connection after getting no response from the client.

Comment: I completely forgot about the `ServerAliveCountMax`, which is probably what solved my problem.

Comment: Are there any specific config on sshd side that woud disable this keep alive attempt from client?  I applied the similar setting but just not working

Answer (score 15):

You can also add these arguments in the ssh command, like so...

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=180 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2 $HOST
```

Answer (score 11):

On Linux and Apple Mac OS X operating systems, the `~/.ssh/config` file enables you to specify many SSH settings, including those that keep alive an SSH connection. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Use your preferred text editor to open the `~/.ssh/config` file on your local computer. Note: If the `.ssh` directory or the config file do not exist, create them.
2. Add the following lines to the config file. The **Host** value can be any name you want; it is simply a label for the other settings. The **Hostname** value is the remote host you want to access; replace **example.com** with your domain name. Replace **username** with your own Hosting account username:

```
    Host example
        Hostname example.com
        Port 7822
        User username
        ServerAliveInterval 240
        ServerAliveCountMax 2
```

With this configuration, the SSH client sends a packet to the server every 240 seconds (4 minutes) to keep the connection alive. If the client does not receive a response after two tries (as specified by the ServerAliveCountMax setting), it closes the connection.

For detailed information about all of the SSH configuration settings available, type `man ssh_config` at the command line.

3. Save the changes to the config file.
4. Connect to your account using SSH. To do this, simply type ssh example where example represents the Host value you specified in step 2.

Monitor the connection. If it still drops, gradually decrease the `ServerAliveInterval` setting in the config file until the connection is stable.

Check the following url for more details https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/accessing-your-account/keeping-ssh-connections-alive